# Pulling data from an api when the JSON record does not have a container name

Tags: python, database, rest, api

I am trying to pull data from the api for our HR System. But when individual photo is pulled the JSON file does not have the container name anymore which breaks my current script.

For the available api when you request all employee photos in 1 request it only returns the thumbnail photo.To get the large photo you have to do it 1 employee at a time and inlclude the employeeid in the url. However the issue is that doing the latter does not present the object name only the items in the document.

```
import json
import pyodbc
import requests

url = "https://someurl.com/api/PersonPhoto"

headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Authorization': "apikey xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)


ID,Photo,PhotoDate,PhotoType = [],[],[],[]

for device in data['PersonPhoto']:

    ID.append(device[u'ID'])

    Photo.append(device[u'Photo'])

    PhotoDate.append(device[u'PhotoDate'])

    PhotoType.append(device[u'PhotoType'])


connStr = pyodbc.connect(
    "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
    "SERVER=TestSrver;"
    "Database=MyDB;"
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;"}"
    )
cursor = connStr.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Employee_Photo2 ([EmployeeID],[PhotoBinary],[PhotoDate],[FileType]) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"

vals = [(int(device[u'ID']), device[u'Photo'], device[u'PhotoDate'],  device[u'PhotoType']) \
       for device in data['PersonPhoto']]

cursor.executemany(sql, vals)   
connStr.commit()
cursor.close()
connStr.close()
```

The above code is working for when I pull all the employees. To pull 1 employee to get the large photo is the same api call except you have to put the employee id on the end of the url.

The issue I am having is that when you make this api call it no longer includes the object name of PersonPhoto in the resulting JSON it just returns the 4 attibutes inside a the curly brackets. So I am not sure how to change the above code to handle the lack of the object name.

JSON that works with above script:

```
{
    "PersonPhoto": [
        {
            "ID": 123,
            "Name": "Test User",
            "Photo": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD",
            "PhotoDate": "2019-05-02T00:00:00",
            "PhotoType": ".jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON that gets returned when you pass the employeeid at the end of the URL:

```
{
    "ID": 123,
    "Name": "Test User",
    "Photo": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKD",
    "PhotoDate": "2019-05-02T00:00:00",
    "PhotoType": ".jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can add exception handling with a try: except: statement to handle the error that occurs when referencing a non existent dictionary key.

From a purely functional standpoint that's a fine solution, but a better practice would probably be to write two separate functions to handle the expected JSON differently depending on the api call you are making

If you are simply ONLY going to handle the new use case, you can just reference the data this way:

```
user = "12345"
url = "https://someurl.com/api/PersonPhoto/{}".format(user)
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
ID = [data['ID']]
Photo = [data['Photo']]
PhotoDate = [data['PhotoDate']]
PhotoType = [data['PhotoType']]
```

Comment: I don't need the above script to handle if key is there or not as I need to use this for the api call where it does not have it as this is the only way to get the large photo to be returned rather than the thumbnail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I will try it out.